# React spread operation of JSX elements inside map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, jsx

I am mapping over a array inside a array for a Picker and am struggeling to figure out how to return the JSX elements rather than the JSX element array.

code example:

```
{modelA.map((mA) => {
    const pickerItems = mA.modelB.map((mA) =>
        <Picker.Item value={mA} ... />,
    );
    return pickerItems;
})}
```

usually my aproach would be to make use of spread operators. but they do not do well in this syntax.

this:

```
{...modelA.map((mA) => {
    const pickerItems = mA.modelB.map((mA) =>
        <Picker.Item value={mA} ... />,
    );
    return pickerItems;
})}
```

is illegal: Spread children are not supported in React.

My dirty take on this would be to configure it pre render. but i'd rather not.

any suggestions?

Comment: Try `modelA.flatMap`

Comment: doesn't seem to be applicable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use reduce:

```
{modelA.reduce((arr,mA) => {
    mA.modelB.forEach((mA) => {
        arr.push(<Picker.Item value={mA} ... />)
    });
    return arr;
}), []}
```